# Looking for a particular class of distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Choose some basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and call one of its directions as "$z$". Let $x$ be a $n-$dimensional random variable s.t for all $3-$tuple of $n-$dimensional rotation matrices  $R_1, R_2$ and $R_3$  I want the following expectation to be a constant (independent of $R_1, R_2$ and $R_3$),

$$\mathbb{E}_{x} \left[ (R_1 x)_z \vert (R_2 x)_z \vert  \vert (R_3 x)_z \vert \right]$$

- Are there non-trivial distributions with such properties? (...trivial cases are when the above is $0$ for the distribution being parity symmetric..)

---

Feel free to assume reasonable restrictions on the support of the distribution - like if say compact support on a sphere or such helps!

Comment: Does $(R_i x)_z$ mean the $z$-coordinate of $R_i x$?

Comment: Yes! Thats exactly what I mean!